# gnome-terminal NOT working after Kali Linux system update

Tags: linux, kali-linux, gnome-terminal

After doing a full Kali linux update using the following command line :

`apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y && apt-get autoclean -y && apt-get autoremove -y`

gnome-terminal stops working showing this error message :

```
    # _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation gvfs (GDaemonVfs) for ‘gio-vfs’
    # Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached
```

this is output from `uname -a` :

```
    Linux LNXBOX 5.3.0-kali2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.3.9-1kali1 (2019-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

this is output from `gnome-terminal --version` :

```
    # GNOME Terminal 3.34.2 using VTE 0.53.0 +GNUTLS
```

this is output from `tail /val/log/syslog` :

```
    Nov 19 18:40:56 LNXBOX org.gnome.Terminal.desktop[1664]: # _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation gvfs (GDaemonVfs) for ‘gio-vfs’
    Nov 19 18:40:56 LNXBOX dbus-daemon[1474]: [session uid=0 pid=1474] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.104' (uid=0 pid=2549 comm="gnome-terminal ")
    Nov 19 18:40:56 LNXBOX systemd[1454]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
    Nov 19 18:40:56 LNXBOX gnome-terminal-server[2554]: /usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server: symbol lookup error: /usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server: undefined symbol: vte_terminal_set_enable_bidi
    Nov 19 18:40:56 LNXBOX systemd[1454]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
    Nov 19 18:40:56 LNXBOX systemd[1454]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    Nov 19 18:40:56 LNXBOX systemd[1454]: Failed to start GNOME Terminal Server.
    Nov 19 18:41:21 LNXBOX org.gnome.Terminal.desktop[1664]: # Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached
```

this is output from `dpkg -l | egrep "gnome-terminal|vte"` :

```
    ii  davtest                                   1.0-1kali3                                       all          Testing tool for WebDAV servers
    ii  gir1.2-vte-2.91:amd64                     0.58.2-1                                         amd64        GObject introspection data for the VTE library
    ii  gnome-terminal                            3.34.2-1kali1                                    amd64        GNOME terminal emulator application
    ii  gnome-terminal-data                       3.34.2-1kali1                                    all          Data files for the GNOME terminal emulator
    ii  libvte-2.91-0:amd64                       0.58.2-1                                         amd64        Terminal emulator widget for GTK+ 3.0 - runtime files
    ii  libvte-2.91-common                        0.58.2-1                                         all          Terminal emulator widget for GTK+ 3.0 - common files
    ii  libvte-2.91-dev:amd64                     0.58.2-1                                         amd64        Terminal emulator widget for GTK+ 3.0 - development files
    ii  libvte-2.91-doc                           0.58.2-1                                         all          Terminal emulator widget for GTK+ 3.0 - documentation
    ii  nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal         3.34.2-1kali1                                    amd64        GNOME terminal emulator application
```

any ideas ?

Comment: If no answer is found here, see http://kali.org/blog and http://forums.kali.org . If neither answer your questions, the Kali IRC channel is #kali-linux, and can be found on irc.freenode.net.

Comment: Please show the output of `dpkg -l | egrep "gnome-terminal|vte"`.

Comment: @grawity i've added the output up in the question

Comment: Kali is absolutely not for beginners. Start on a more complete unix, switch to kali when you already know what you're doing. Compulsory kali link - [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: @DavidPostill Ok , i've removed Kali completely from my computer, and am sending you this comment by post , BTW i'll mark your comment as the best answer, thanx !